# My excel date is converted into text in php

Tags: php, excel, date, xls

My excel has start date as header and the value is 05/30/16 but when i am reading this value in php, it is saying 'MayMay/MonMon/20162016'. Why is it happening. I want real value.

```
$excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$excel->read('sample.xls');
$x=1;
while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
  echo "\t<tr>\n";
  $y=1;
  while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {
    $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
    echo "\t\t<td>$cell</td>\n"; 
    $y++;
  } 
  echo "\t</tr>\n";
  $x++;
}
```

Comment: How are you reading this in PHP?  Really information provided.

Comment: Don't tell me! Let me guess!.... you're using an Excel date format mask like `MM/DD/YY` in a PHP date function.... PHP date masks are __not__ the same as Excel date masks..... read the [PHP Docs for date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: My excel date format is MM/DD/YY;

Comment: So where did you get this copy of Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(), it looks as though it's rather broken

Comment: [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) check this url. `D` represents day of the week. Not the `date`. Use `d-m-Y` instead of `MM\DD\YY`

Answer (score 0):

To get dates, use

```
$cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y])
    ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]['raw']
    : '';
```

This will return the "raw" MS Excel serialized timestamp value, a number like `41944`.

An MS Excel timestamp is typically the number of days since 1st January 1900 (though it could be number of days since 1st January 1904 if the spreadsheet was created using the Mac 1904 calendar)

You need to convert this to a Unix Timestamp in order to use PHP date functions with it.... depending on which Calendar is being used, a quick and dirty conversion:

**Windows 1900 Calendar**

```
$unixTimestamp = ($excelTimestamp - 25569) * 86400;
```

and for the reverse

```
$excelTimestamp = ($unixTimestamp / 86400) + 25569;
```

**Mac 1904 Calendar**

```
$unixTimestamp = ($excelTimestamp - 24107) * 86400;
```

and for the reverse

```
$excelTimestamp =  ($unixTimestamp / 86400) + 24107;
```

So MS Excel `41944` => `$unixTimestamp = (41944 - 25569) * 86400;` giving `1414800000` which is the unix timestamp for `1st November 2014`

Once you have a unix timestamp, you can then use PHP's standard date() function or DateTime objects to manipulate and format it as you wish

```
echo date('d-M-Y', $unixTimestamp);
```

Comment: The problem is that `$cell` returning already MayMay/MonMon/20162016.

Comment: Then if you can't access the raw value, you'll need to fix the bug in the library itself